# jackson kotlin - Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson2

I am getting a json string from Fitbit API. I want to save dateTime and value fields in a List object. I´m using jackson module kotlin. I have created ActivitiesSteps data class for this.

I don´t know how to avoid "activities-steps" field and I´m getting stucked.

This is the JSON body(provided in variable 'jsonSteps' to readValue method in my code below):

```
  {  
   "activities-steps":[  
      {  
         "dateTime":"2018-04-17",
         "value":"11045"
      },
      {  
         "dateTime":"2018-04-18",
         "value":"14324"
      },
      {  
         "dateTime":"2018-05-16",
         "value":"11596"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my class to save my data:

```
data class ActivitiesSteps(var dateTime: String, var value: String)
```

Here is my code using jackson:

```
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
val stepsList = mapper.readValue<List<ActivitiesSteps>>(jsonSteps)
```

And the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of 
START_OBJECT token at 

[Source: (String)"{"activities-steps":[
{"dateTime":"2018-04-17","value":"11045"},
{"dateTime":"2018-04-25","value":"8585"},
{"dateTime":"2018-04-26","value":"11218"},
{"dateTime":"2018-04-27","value":"10462"},
{"dateTime":"2018-04"[truncated 762 chars]; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have an outer object that matches the top level of the JSON.  In this case change your code to:

```
data class ActivityConfig(
    @JsonProperty("activities-steps") val steps: List<ActivitiesSteps> = emptyList()
)

data class ActivitiesSteps(var dateTime: String, var value: String)

val stepsList = mapper.readValue<ActivityConfig>(jsonSteps).steps
```

You can use default values with the Jackson Kotin module if you want the list to always be present, and also you do not need `var` members in the data class if you want, `val` work fine with Jackson as well unless you really want to mutate the values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the array you're trying to get at is wrapped in an object, which you're feeding into Jackson and asking for a List back. JSON object-to-Java List isn't a translation that Jackson understands, so it's choking.

I would create a class that wraps that List and try deserializing to that.